# mysql large table sometime missing records

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, transactions, innodb

Database have a table with almost 323,354 of records. I am using Zend(PHP) framework to build application and use trnsaction. This table has a parent table(master). While updating this parent-children suit, our procedure is to delete all items already with parent_id and reinsert new records, instead of updating each slave records separately. But the problem is sometimes some records are missing from the slave table. Didn't found any coding error and also used transaction to prevent partial inserts or updates. Is this a mysql problem?

Comment: It would be highly surprising if it were a MySQL problem, but any large software system could have bugs.

Comment: Can you guess what is the problem?

Comment: If you have multiple clients deleting and inserting records, it sounds like a race condition.  Complicated to debug.

Comment: any alternative solution?

Comment: We have 2 databases/applications, but only one have multiple clients.

Comment: but problem exists in both

Comment: problem relating to TRANSACTION?